# Solr 6 and carrot2 integration

Tags: solr, carrot2

I'm trying to use carrot2 with my Solr 6 installation, but all I get when calling a query is:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/carrotsearch/hppc/ObjectHashSet
06:04:55 solr.1   |     at org.carrot2.text.preprocessing.PreprocessingContext.<init>(PreprocessingContext.java:53)
06:04:55 solr.1   |     at org.carrot2.text.preprocessing.pipeline.CompletePreprocessingPipeline.preprocess(CompletePreprocessingPipeline.java:65)
06:04:55 solr.1   |     at org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm.cluster(LingoClusteringAlgorithm.java:191)
06:04:55 solr.1   |     at org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm.access$000(LingoClusteringAlgorithm.java:63)
06:04:55 solr.1   |     at org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm$1.process(LingoClusteringAlgorithm.java:177)`

I've tried downloading the most recent carrot2 and adding:
 `<lib dir=".../carrot2-workbench-3.12.0/plugins/" regex=".*\.jar" />`

where the `com.carrotsearch.hppc` jar is, but it didn't change anything.

Any help on how to make it work would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your configuration. I just downloaded Solr 6.0.0 and followed the default instructions (running techproducts example), everything worked fine.

HPPC is present in Solr's default libraries so it should definitely be found on classpath.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Clustering

Comment: Can you provide the download link/page you used? I couldn't find the jar in my current setup.

Comment: The "download" button on http://lucene.apache.org/solr/mirrors-solr-latest-redir.html. You fetch Solr's ZIP package, then start the example with clustering on. cwiki page above has the details step-by-step.